# check whether particular subject is in another columns and duplicates within each column in r

Tags: r, duplicates

Here is data:
Example 1: complete

```
complete <- c("A", "B", "C","J", "C1", "L", "J2", "D", "M", "N")
lst1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "N", NA,"A", "C", "D", NA )
lst2 <- c(NA, NA, NA,"A", "L", NA, "C1", "J2", "J2", "B")
datf <- data.frame (complete, lst1, lst2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Example 2: incomplete and duplicated

```
complete <- c("A", "B", "C","J", "C1", "L", "C", "D", "M", "N")
lst1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "N", NA,"A", "C", "D1", NA )
lst2 <- c(NA, NA, NA,"A", "L", NA, "C1", "J2", "J2", "B2")
datf2 <- data.frame (complete, lst1, lst2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to check :
(1) if the members of lst1 and lst2 are at least present at least once in complete.
  If not present, then a stop message will say that this "?" is present in lst1 or lst2 (whatever correct) but not in complete.
My trial:
    for example 1

```
if (datf$lst1 %in%  datf$complete | datf$lst2 %in%  datf$complete) {
     stop ("the subject in lst1 or lst2 must be complete list ")} else {
     cat("I am fine")
     }

I am fineWarning message:
In if (datf$lst1 %in% datf$complete | datf$lst2 %in% datf$complete) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why is this error message and how can I supress it ?

```
  Example 2:
    if (datf2$lst1 %in%  datf2$complete | datf2$lst2 %in%  datf2$complete) {
         stop ("the subject in lst1 or lst2 must be complete list ")} else {
         cat("I am fine")
         }
   Although there is potential errors the error message is same:
      I am fineWarning message:
    In if (datf2$lst1 %in% datf2$complete | datf2$lst2 %in% datf2$complete) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Also is there way to provide names that do not match as part of error message.

(2) If any member of complete is dublicated.

**Edit:**

```
Expected answer:
Example1 <-  all members of lst1 and lst2 are also member of complete 

expacted message here is "I am fine"

Example2 <-
B2, J2, is member of lst2 but not complete, D1 is member of lst1 but not complete. 
complete have two C, so C is duplicated. 
The function will stop and print a message 

"B2 and J2 are member of lst1, but not in complete 
 D1  is member of lst2, but not in complete,
 check completeness" 
"C is duplicated in complete"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> datf$lst1 %in% datf$complete | datf$lst2 %in% datf$complete
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

from `?'if'` the argument for if is a length-one logical vector that is not NA.

```
> na.omit(datf2$lst1)[!na.omit(datf2$lst1)%in%datf2$complete]
[1] "D1"
> na.omit(datf2$lst2)[!na.omit(datf2$lst2)%in%datf2$complete]
[1] "J2" "J2" "B2"

> datf2$complete[duplicated(datf2$complete)]
[1] "C"
```

the above should help you to compose a function to do what you propose.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problem, is there way to solve what I intend to achieve ?